# Shuffle tree (recursion)

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

I have tree constructed recursively from the following class:

```
public class Node
{
    public byte Symbol { get; set; }
    public int Frequency { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }
    public Node Left { get; set; }
}
```

How to shuffle that tree?

Comment: Is it just a tree or a BST, etc.?

Comment: Assuming that the tree need not be ordered (as pointed above) would not traversing it and creating a list out of the values, shuffling that list and traverse the tree again in the same order and overwrite the value work?

Comment: It is just a tree (Huffman Tree). Not BST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way, but you can do it as follows:

1. Flatten the tree into a list of nodes.
2. Shuffle the data contents of the nodes in that list without changing the Left or Right references.

So, to flatten the tree:

```
static IEnumerable<Node> FlattenTree(Node root)
{
    if (root != null)
    {
        yield return root;

        foreach (var node in FlattenTree(root.Left))
            yield return node;

        foreach (var node in FlattenTree(root.Right))
            yield return node;
    }
}
```

Then write a [Fisher-Yates shuffler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle the contents of the nodes in a list:

```
static void Shuffle(List<Node> nodes, Random rng)
{
    // Fisher-Yates shuffle.

    for (int n = nodes.Count; n > 1; )
    {
        int k = rng.Next(n);
        --n;
        Swap(nodes[n], nodes[k]);
    }
}

static void Swap(Node a, Node b)
{
    byte tempSymbol = a.Symbol;
    a.Symbol = b.Symbol;
    b.Symbol = tempSymbol;

    int tempFrequency = a.Frequency;
    a.Frequency = b.Frequency;
    b.Frequency = tempFrequency;
}
```

Finally flatten the tree into a list and then shuffle the contents of the nodes in that list:

```
static void ShuffleTree(Node root, Random rng)
{
    var allNodes = FlattenTree(root).ToList();
    Shuffle(allNodes, rng);
}
```

This requires enough space to make a copy of all the node references in the tree, and it has O(N) complexity when flattening the tree and O(N) when shuffling (so it is O(N) overall).

Note that you need to pass a `Random` into ShuffleTree(). If you are calling it multiple times, create just one Random object and pass the same one to each call to avoid problems with creating a new Random so frequently that multiple instances use the same seed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a tree and nothing else. I would traverse the tree and add every node to a dictionary with a random value as key. Then order it and build up the new tree from by adding values in order.

Obviously you will possibly also have to generate a random int between x and y that specifies how many children nodes a node can have and attach that also to a node if it is not a binary tree but by you code example I presume it is.

```
//Traverse the tree and put it in input
Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
List<Node> sortedList = input.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToList();
```

- Get first item from sortedList and put it in working list
- loop through working list
- Get the next 2 items from sorted list. (if there is any left)
- Add it to the working list item
- Remove the current working list item.
- Add the 2 children nodes to the working list
- We continue until the working list is empty.

This will obviously create a tree with all branches more or less the same length

Comment: Please provide an example of how to do it, or at least some pseudo-code.